# Error "Bad received type 'NSMutableArray'"when archive program

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, archive

I building the program read text file but when I debug, it runs ok, But when I archive program, it show error `

```
"Bad received type 'NSMutableArray'"
```

So I cannot archive my program.
This is my code:

```
NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

            // first, separate by new line
            temptextString =[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

            allLinedStrings = [temptextString mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"Line array%@",allLinedStrings);
            writeArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            tempIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for(NSInteger i =0 ;i < [allLinedStrings count] ; i++)
            {
                if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[LANGUAGE]"])
                {
                    [tempIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
                }
                else if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[AP]"])
                {
                    [tempIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
                }
                else if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[FTP]"])
                {
                    [tempIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
                }
                else if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[Wi-Fi Setting]"])
                {
                    [tempIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
                }
                else if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[MISC]"])
                {
                    [tempIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"Temp Index %@",tempIndex);
```

I don't know why is that so. Please help me fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Where do you get the error? 2. In every case you add the same string!?

Comment: I get error where allLinestring (NSMutableArray) in loopfor(NSInteger i =0 ;i < [allLinedStrings count] ; i++) @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: I get error in  if([allLinedStrings[i] isEqualToString:@"[LANGUAGE]"])...

Comment: Hmm, cannot see the mistake. You should cast i to long (+stringWithFormat:), because your app can be build for 32 bit, too.

Comment: No, my app build for 64bit

Comment: I dont know what is that so. Can you help me? Thanks much

Comment: Can you share sample project to reproduce the problem?